# Docker container port 6002 connection refused

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Operating System: Docker for Windows.
OSType: linux.
Architecture: x86_64

I have an ASP.NET core web app running inside a Docker container. The below is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 6002

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AdvPersonApi.csproj", "AdvPersonApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "AdvPersonApi/AdvPersonApi.csproj"
COPY . ./AdvPersonApi/
WORKDIR "/src/AdvPersonApi"
RUN dotnet build "AdvPersonApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "AdvPersonApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
EXPOSE 6002
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AdvPersonApi.dll"]
```

The app builds successfully. I also am able to create the Docker image, and run it. I want the app to be accessible at localhost:6002. I used the below command to create the container:

```
docker run -p 6002:6002 --name advpersonapicontainerv2 advpersonapi:v2
```

I see that the containers are created and running.

The below is the result of docker ps:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
0484b184aeb8        advpersonapi:v2     "dotnet AdvPersonApi…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:6002->6002/tcp   advpersonapicontainerv2
```

The issue is that I am not able to access the app at Container port 6002. The below command gives connection refused:

```
    docker exec 0484b184aeb8 curl http://localhost:6002/api/person/time
     % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 6002: Connection refused
```

However, if I try

> docker exec 0484b184aeb8 curl http://**localhost:80**/api/person/time

, I get the response. I am new to Docker. What should I do to map the host port 6002 correctly to the container port 6002?

Comment: Does your application host on port 6002 when not run in docker or do you need to tell it to host on that port?

Comment: @zero298 if the question is about running from Visual Studio, in IISExpress it is configured to run on a different port (44370), and it works fine.

Comment: Then port 80 is likely the default port. Try -p 6002:80 and curling from the host, not from within the container itself. Its -p HOST_PORT:INNER_PORT.

Comment: Try entering the container (https://www.shellhacks.com/docker-enter-container/) and running netstat. See if the desired port is open. Maybe the web application isn't opening the port number you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is going on. I had to force Kestrel to listen to port 6002, by adding the below to the appsettings.json.

```
 "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://+:6002"
      }
    }
  }
```

Credit to the hint provided by @Timothy John Laird in the above comment

Comment: There's no need to change the port inside the container. Change it from the outside, not the inside.

Comment: Refer to my comment to your answer above. I tried that option and I have mentioned that clearly in my question - docker run -p 6002:6002.

Answer (score -1):

The app inside the container is listening on 80, so in your Dockerfile expose port 80 instead of 6002.

```
EXPOSE 80
```

Then map host port 6002 to container port 80 when you run the container:

```
docker run -p 6002:80 --name advpersonapicontainerv2 advpersonapi:v2
```

It's best to have containerized apps listening on standard ports like 80 or 8000. You don't want to update the Dockerfile to get it to listen to other ports. That's the job of the runtime mapping at the host level.

Comment: I wanted the container to listen on a different port (6002 in this case). This is because, this container is one among a couple of other containers to be deployed inside a K8s pod. When all these containers in the pod listen to port 80, the K8s deployment failed as soon as the second container was deployed. At this time, the logs of the failed container in the pod has shown that Kestrel threw an exception saying port 80 is already used. I believe this is because IP addresses and Ports are at the Pod scope in K8s. I tried setting "containerPort" in the K8s deployment yaml, which did not work